# Python Socket - How to properly handle timeout properly?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Using

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

i wonder how someone can handle if a timeout. Let's say i send packets over and recieve them as shown above, everything works, except that when a transmitter stops sending further packets, the socket on the reciever side just waits and continues if a new paket come. However, i would like to have some kind of counter that waits for a specific time and closes the socket after no new paket comes in.

To do so, i have to somehow catch that moment when data is no longer received but i haven't found really a way of doing it properly with socket

I've tried something like

```
   try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    except:
        print("connection lost")
```

but it doesn't work (expected that already). I also tried a while loop like so:

```
while True:
             data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

which works, but again i cannot check if the connection is lost.

Any ideas how to deal with this? Thanks

Comment: If you're claiming that exceptions don't work, you are mistaken. If by 'connection loss' you mean 'peer has closed connection', you need to test for that case, which is not an exception.

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: Well i mean by that the timeout. If a package is received but the transmitter stops sending further packages for quite some time, one has to catch that case. In my case the stream just stops and continues in case there is a packet coming. However, i would like to have some kind of counter / timer that waits for a specific time until it closes the socket when no further packet arrives.

Comment: What timeout? Have you *set* a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.settimeout() function to set the socket to wait for a particular amount of time for receving data. If you are creating socket as socket.SOCK_DGRAM, it is a UDP socket. UDP is connectionless protocol. With TCP sockets you can simply use recv() and send() method. You can also put your code under "try catch" as shown below to handle socket error...

```
try:
    # Code
except socket.error as exception:
    print("socket.error : ", exception)
finally:
    pass
```